# VS Code Jupyter Notebook Output Cell Word Wrapping Not Working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm selecting text data from an SFrame and printing it. The text is really long, and the cell gets a horizontal scrollbar to view it. I would like to have it wrap to a newline and fit in my window, not to have a horizontal scrollbar.

I tried enabling/disabling the vscode command `View: Toggle Word Wrap`, but that didn't change the output, even upon rerunning the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, VS Code doesn't currently support word wrap in the output or terminal windows.

You can try to use `textwrap` package manually.

Add the following codes to your script:

```py
import textwrap

wrapped_text = textwrap.fill(text, width=80) #text is the object which you want to print
print(wrapped_text)
```